# How to prevent InnoSetup from creating Start menu shortcuts?

Tags: inno-setup

I use InnoSetup to create application installer. Since I am installing a plugin for an existing application, I don't want the application icon to show up in the Start menu shortcuts. How to prevent InnoSetup from creating Start menu shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

InnoSetup will only create icons if you have entries in your `[Icons]` section.  Remove all of the entries and your installer won't create any icons.

Answer (score 0):

In [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6616857/devnull)'s scenario, another task to do could be to hide the installed plugin from the list of the installed Programs and Features on Windows control panel.

In order to so, you need to add this line of code in your InnoSetup script:

```
CreateUninstallRegKey=no
```